# SerialException: could not open port (Access is denied)

Tags: python, serial-port

I am writing Python v2.x in Windows7 OS. When I run my code, the following error happens frequently.

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
```

Here are what I did:

1) I check device manager, `COM 4` can be seen, but cannot open

2) In my code, I do close `COM` port after using it

3) Here is `COM` config in my code: `ser = serial.Serial( "COM4", 9600, timeout=0.05)`

4) I reboot computer, the problem is gone, but it happens again after a while

5) I wonder it is a problem related to my Python code or Windows system?

So considering above fact, could anyone help me out? Thanks and Happy New Year!

=)

Comment: the piece related to COM port config is here: ser = serial.Serial( "COM4", 9600, timeout=0.05)

Comment: That's not enough...need to see how you are using `ser`...or may be something else that you thought it's not relate but it just could be.

Comment: um.. i think i figure it out. I notice that the error msg said my python is win32bit, however, my system is win64...could that be the reason? If so, why...?

Comment: Mostly probably, your `COM4` port is being used by another process...check if you have another application using it...

Comment: yea..i do think about that, but i only run one program with serial close ended. But i would like to check if it is occupied by another app. Can u enlighten me how to check?

Comment: In Windows..I really have no idea...but I would like to see your code if possible...otherwise I can't be of much help

Comment: The COM Surrogate is the `dllhost.exe` process.

Comment: Can you try connecting to `COM4` through Hyperterminal to see if it's being used by other program?...of course after you stop your Python script

Comment: Have you solved this one? I have the same problem. But when I run the app for the first time the port can be opened. It looks like the port is still occupied when I close the app. Maybe there is a way to free the port before closing the app, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 45):

I had Ultimaker Cura Slicer (for my 3D printer) open, and that was holding control of the COM3 port for some reason. Once I killed that app, then it (VSCode) worked fine for uploading code to my ESP-8266

Comment: Oh my god. I could have spent hours fiddling with settings and it never would have occurred to me that Cura could be the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Had the exact same issue! You saved my day! :D

Comment: Very good hint! Closing Cura made it work right away.

Comment: thanks, i was having the same issue where another tool was holding the same port.

Comment: for example In platformIO you should to close the `Serial Monitor` before erase flash or upload filesystem image.

Comment: And its still a problem. Thank your for the solution

Comment: What the heck, lol. I'm so glad I found this post after like some seconds of googling! This could've easily cost me some minutes.

Comment: That's incredible. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 31):

You port COM4 may be open in the arduino IDE serial monitor.
close the serial monitor in the arduino IDE.
This may solve your issue.

Comment: Ideally you'd explain how to close it in the arduino ide, as it's not obvious...

Comment: I spent 6 hours trying to solve this problem, and you saved my day, just close the serial, but I close even Arduino Ide, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are talking about this error.

serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM6': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5).

It means that the COM6 is being used by some other program e.g Arduino IDE. So close the serial monitor in IDE and then run your code. Now this is one of the many possibilities only.

Answer (score 1):

Had you closed your serial after you excute your project?
Maybe you can try to close you port and open it again everytime when you execute you program.
just like:

```
ser = Serial('COM3', 115200)
if not ser.isOpen():
    ser.open()
print('com3 is open', ser.isOpen())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem trying to download code to an ESP32 from my Windows 10 PC. I downloaded and installed the Serial Port Monitor app from https://serial-port-monitor.org which showed that my MalwareBytes Antimalware was interfering with opening the port.  I disabled MBAM Ransomware Protection and all was well.  Remember to turn Ransomware Protection back on when you've finished!